Centering the text in FormLabel in shadcn component
I am using shadcn's form component. In the form component, along side button I want to include a checkbox. The checkbox has the label, I wist to align both checkbox and label in the middle, but unable to do so. (For styling I am using tailwindcss)

Here's my code:

            <div className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-4">
              <LoadingBtn type="submit" loading={isSubmitting}>
                Submit
              </LoadingBtn>
              <FormField
                control={control}
                name="shoutout"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center space-x-3">
                    <FormControl>
                      <Checkbox
                        checked={field.value}
                        onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormLabel className="text-center justify-center items-center font-light text-sm italic">
                      Add &quot;created by Longpost&quot; to the end of your
                      post
                    </FormLabel>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>

Please help me what i am missing? As it's already causing me to pull out my hair.

perhaps you could share a sandbox example like this. would be easier for others to help

probably caused by the space-y-2 in the FormItem. maybe override it from your className and see <FormItem className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">

Replace FormItem with a div, or you can modify FormItem

Could you clarify why replacing FormItem with a div or modifying it would help align the checkbox and label? Providing a bit more detail on the reasoning would make your answer clearer.
